# Is data observed from the internet counted as primary data?

Tags: dataset, terminology, observational-study, variable, internet

I need to find primary data (2 variable) to conduct a research about correlation.  Are data that I observed from the internet (example: from youtube.com/amazon.com) counted as primary data?

Comment: It can be, but depends on what it is you are taking from the internet

Comment: Example: A store's rating from Amazon and total of product the store sell

Answer (score 2):

This would depend on how the data is collected and presented; as you mention, source is important.

Primary sources of data are those that are immediate, first-hand data from those who had a direct connection with that data.
To be included as primary data, you would have to ensure it is data pulled from a source that had direct contact with the data, and that it was not culled from another source.  Additionally, primary data is data that is primary level (think: individual subject responses where a line of data equals a person's response, etc).

For websites or otherwise, you will need to closely examine what the data source is, whether it is a full data set of the collection, and if this data is temporally-complete for the collection period. In other words, check to ensure the study or source is in the process of collecting data and what their data holders' policy is regarding editing responses; primary source collectors being able to delete or change data.
In your example of views in Youtube, if you were looking at the number of comments to a video, owners of the video and YouTube moderators have the authority to delete comments.  In this case, a count of comments would NOT be considered a primary source from a technical standpoint. Views may constitute primary data, but only if it is viewed as a variable within your data set (e.g. views on this video are one data line, views on this other video are another data line, etc. etc.). Here is YouTube's policy regarding counts of views and how they are tabulated:  https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2991785?hl=en

Good sources of primary data online are governmental databases, collections of health data, education databases.  Statista, Mergent, Social Explorer and ProQuest Statistical Insight are just a few of the places where you might find good primary data source material to work with.  Good luck!

Comment: thank you very much for the answer

Comment: If the answer helped you, consider upvote it!

Comment: Or, accept the answer!